# matplotlib animation doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote this code for plotting a dynamic diagram using matplotlib, but it doesn't work:

```
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
def animate(i):
graph_data = open ('data.txt','r').read()
lines = graph_data.split('\n')
xs = []
ys = []
for line in lines:
    if len(line) > 1:
        x, y = line.split(',')
        # print(x,y)
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)
# print(xs,ys)
# ax1.clear()
ax1.plot(xs, ys)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
```

the data.txt datas are like these:

```
1,0.8
2,1.4
3,1.4
4,2.6
5,1.5
6,1.6
7,2.4
```

i use python2.7 and newest version of matplotlib

Comment: Please take care of indentation as this is (in python) part of your programs' semantics  - it might be the case that therein lies your problem

Comment: Your example is not working. There should be an indent after `def animate(i):`. Could you please correct this?

Comment: in program its ok, here when i was pasting it here its so

Answer (score 0):

You need to have ax1.plot inside of animate.

```
def animate(i):
   graph_data = open ('data.txt','r').read()
   lines = graph_data.split('\n')
   xs = []
   ys = []
   for line in lines:
      if len(line) > 1:
      x, y = line.split(',')
      xs.append(x)
      ys.append(y)
   ax1.plot(xs, ys)
```

when written like this it works on my machine.

Comment: it is there, i figure out that problem is with the version of matplotlib, it doesn't support certain GTK3 scenarios